# Dgraph deployed using helm chart not working as expected in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, dgraph

We have deployed the latest version of Dgraph cluster using Helm chart.
We are able to open the ratel UI. But the ACL function is not available for us.

We also tried the ACL helm method mention in this blog
https://dgraph.io/docs/enterprise-features/access-control-lists/

We are not able to login using default user and backup is also not working.

I have 30 days enterprise trail version.

We also tried the ACL helm method mention in this blog
https://dgraph.io/docs/enterprise-features/access-control-lists/

We are not able to login using default user and backup is also not working.

I have 30 days enterprise trail version.